# Amazon SQS is throwing Access Denied Exception Error 403

Tags: java, aws-sdk, amazon-sqs

I am getting the following exception when I changed the aws sdk version from 1.10.77 to 1.11.490. Everything is working before when I used 1.10.77 and now I am getting the below error.

Any suggestions are helpful. Thanks

```
 <dependency>
                <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
                <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
                <version>1.11.490</version>
                <!--<version>1.10.77</version>-->
        </dependency>   
    <dependency>
                <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
                <artifactId>amazon-sqs-java-messaging-lib</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Here is code where Iam instantiating the sqs bean

```
        <bean id="credentialsProviderBean" class="com.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain"/>

            <bean id="connectionFactoryBuilder" class="com.amazon.sqs.javamessaging.SQSConnectionFactory$Builder">
                <property name="regionName" value="us-east-1"/>
                <property name="numberOfMessagesToPrefetch" value="5"/>
                <property name="awsCredentialsProvider" ref="credentialsProviderBean"/>
            </bean>

            <bean id="sqsConnectionFactory" class="com.amazon.sqs.javamessaging.SQSConnectionFactory"
                  factory-bean="connectionFactoryBuilder"
                  factory-method="build"/>

 Access to the resource https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/12234/ESMP-X-J-SHORTS-UI-SHORTS_INCOMING_SQS is denied. (Service: AmazonSQS; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: 93e4c319-ddfd-5687-ae9f-97e97a5581c5)
                at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1701)
                at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1356)
                at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1102)
                at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:759)
                at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:733)
                at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:715)
                at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:675)
                at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:657)
                at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:521)
                at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.doInvoke(AmazonSQSClient.java:2215)
                at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.invoke(AmazonSQSClient.java:2182)
                at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.invoke(AmazonSQSClient.java:2171)
                at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.executeReceiveMessage(AmazonSQSClient.java:1601)
                at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.receiveMessage(AmazonSQSClient.java:1573)
                at com.amazon.sqs.javamessaging.AmazonSQSMessagingClientWrapper.receiveMessage(AmazonSQSMessagingClientWrapper.java:319)
                at com.amazon.sqs.javamessaging.SQSMessageConsumerPrefetch.getMessages(SQSMessageConsumerPrefetch.java:216)
                at com.amazon.sqs.javamessaging.SQSMessageConsumerPrefetch.run(SQSMessageConsumerPrefetch.java:180)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)

             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    02-27-2019 09:57:44 [ConsumerPrefetchThread-1] 
    com.amazon.sqs.javamessaging.SQSMessageConsumerPrefetch  WARN  
    (SQSMessageConsumerPrefetch.java:220) - Encountered exception during receive 
    in ConsumerPrefetch thread
    javax.jms.JMSSecurityException: AmazonServiceException: receiveMessage. 
    RequestId: 93e4c319-ddfd-5687-ae9f-97e97a5581c5
    HTTPStatusCode: 403 AmazonErrorCode: AccessDenied
                at com.amazon.sqs.javamessaging.AmazonSQSMessagingClientWrapper.handleException(AmazonSQSMessagingClientWrapper.java:394)
```